# Javascript string instead of object expected

Tags: javascript, string, object

```
var x = {};
x.a = {y:5};
x.b = {z:6};

for (prop in x) console.log(typeof prop); // returns "string". Why not "object"?
```

Shouldn't it return object? How do I get around this?

Comment: You should look at what `prop` is: http://jsfiddle.net/NnLrh/1/

Comment: How about reading [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)?

Answer (score 1):

If you output the prop's themselves, you'll see they are the keys: "a", "b".

Comment: The values that `prop` gets in the loop are the string "a", and then the string "b".

Comment: Right, but why does it get the string when "a" is an object?

Comment: @user1019031: `"a"` is not an object, it is a string. `x.a` (or `x["a"]`) is an object. Have a look at the documentation I linked to in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

all of these responses are right, but perhaps you would see it better with a corrected example:

```
var x = {};
x.a = {y:5};
x.b = {z:6};

for (prop in x) console.log(typeof prop); // returns "string"
for (prop in x) console.log(prop); // returns "a", then "b"
for (prop in x) console.log(typeof x[prop]); // returns "object"
for (prop in x) console.log(x[prop]); // returns {y:5}, then {z:6}
```

Comment: Ah got it thank you! Just what I needed to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Its returning the name of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to

```
for (prop in x) console.log(typeof x[prop]);
```

The `x[prop]` part takes the property name, called `prop` (it is of type string) and returns the property `x.prop`, which for the case of a and b, will return object.